# Facebook Graph API not return friends id only count return

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook graph API to retrieve my friends list . but my api request only give count of friend.

```
{
   "data": [

   ],
   "summary": {
      "total_count": 305
   }
}
```

I am requesting with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=xxxx
```

I have permission of

> user_friends

Comment: I nominated this question for reopen. The questions are different because `total_count` was returned. It's a whole different ball game. In this question, the permission was requested and some of the data is returned. The problem is how to see the whole data...

Comment: As of 2.8, `taggable_friends` is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Since v2.0 for the Graph API, `/me/friends` only returns friends who authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission too. More information about getting access to all friends: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)